# calculate percentage from BigQuery table Standard SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

```
| eta   | arrived    | 
+-------+------------+
| 06:47 |    07:00   | 
| 08:30 |    08:20   | 
| 10:30 |    10:38   | 
+-------+------------+
```

if have a table like above and i want to calculate how many of the arrived is within the ETA, for example, the first and the third one is within the eta time but the second one is not, so i would like to calculate the percentage or say out of 3, 2 were on time. how would i do this in Bigquery Standard SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is:

```
select avg(case when arrived < eta then 1.0 else 0 end) as ratio_on_time
from t;
```

You can use `100.0` if you actually want a number from 0 to 100.

Answer (score 1):

Count the number of rows matching the condition, then divide by the total count:

```
SELECT
  100 * COUNTIF(arrived < eta) / COUNT(*) AS percent_on_time
FROM dataset.table
```

I reversed the condition since my understanding is that you would want to check that the arrival time was less than the ETA.

Answer (score 1):

> i would like to ...  say "out of 3, 2 were on time"

Yet another "option"

```
#standardSQL
SELECT FORMAT('Out of %i, %i were on time', COUNT(1), COUNTIF(arrived < eta)) summary
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

if to apply to dummy data in your question - result is:

```
Row summary  
1   Out of 3, 1 were on time
```